# How to solve this driver error when installing tortilla adapter on windows 8?

Tags: windows

Getting error 'updatedriverforplugandplaydevice()' after creating tortilla.exe from tortilla.sln

[image]

Comment: disable driver signature reinforcement before executing it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/CrowdStrike/Tortilla/issues/5) thread would suggest that you need to be running as admin.

Failing that, try following the parts of the [README](https://github.com/CrowdStrike/Tortilla/blob/master/README.txt) that explain how to enable support for test-signed drivers.

Comment: Followed all build instruction and still getting same error. Do i have to manually create the driver package for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it on Windows 10:

1. Download Tor [Tor expert bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download) and run it. By defaut, it is just a command line window that you need to keep open. Alternativey, you can [install it as a service](https://miloserdov.org/?p=1839)
2. Download [Tortilla](https://www.crowdstrike.com/resources/community-tools/tortilla-tool/)
3. If enabled, disable UEFI secure boot on your Windows machine
4. once it is disabled, open a command prompt as admin and run `bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON`
5. reboot your machine
6. Install tortilla by running the exe as admin (and dont close the command line window)
7. Confirm that you want to install the driver
8. Use the Tortilla Adapter as bridged adapter for your VM

You need to have both Tor and Tortilla started everytime you want to use this setup (the adapter will only be installed once).